# arraylists, listviews and button

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, android-button

I've spent a few days researching and I haven't found the answer I'm looking for so maybe you guys could help out a little.

My app is a trading card deck builder. I have two ArrayLists, database and currentDeck and both are working as they should. The task that I am trying to accomplish is to add the selected item of database as a new item in currentDeck.

Here is the main method:

```
public class DeckBuilderActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

ArrayList<Card> database = new ArrayList<Card>(); //create new arraylist of datatype card
ArrayList<Card> currentDeck = new ArrayList<Card>(); //create arraylist for currently loaded deck

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_deck_builder);

    //begin method to create main database.
    cardfightMainDatabase(database);

    //format display in listview
    DatabaseAdapter adapter = new DatabaseAdapter(this, database);
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.card_database_listview);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    //format display in deck view
    DeckAdapter adapter2 = new DeckAdapter(this, currentDeck);
    GridView gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.deckGridView);
    gv.setAdapter(adapter2);

    //set up click event
    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mMessageClickedHandler = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {

            //link image view
            ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cardDisplay);

            //link scrollable textview
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cardDataDisplay);

            // Do something in response to the click
            //set image id
            int imageId = database.get(position).getCardImgID();

            //display image to imageview
            iv.setImageResource(imageId);

            //display text to textview
            //Print card name, expansion, card number, skill and flavor text to scrollable textview
            tv.setText(database.get(position).getCardName() + "\nExpansion Set: " + database.get(position).getExpansion() +
                        "\nCard #: " + database.get(position).getCardNum() + "\nSkill:\n" + database.get(position).getUnitSkill()
                + "\nFlavor Text:\n" + "\"" + database.get(position).getCardLore()+ "\"");

        }
    };

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(mMessageClickedHandler);
} //end OnCreate Method
```

The Database Adapter

```
public class DatabaseAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Card> {


//constructor
public DatabaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Card> database)
{
    super(context, 0, database); //call parent
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    //get the data item for this position
    Card card = getItem(position);
    //check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view



    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(database_layout, parent, false);
    }
    //Lookup view for data population
    ImageView cardIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.card_icon);
    TextView cardInfo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.card_info);
    TextView cardStats = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.card_stats);

    //set text views
    cardInfo.setText("<" + card.getUnitGrade() + ">" + " " + card.getCardName());
    cardStats.setText("Power " + card.getUnitPower() + "   Shield: " + card.getUnitShield());
    //set image view
    int cardIconId = card.getCardImgID(); //get image assigned to card and store as local int
    cardIcon.setImageResource(cardIconId); //populate imageview in list
    return convertView;
    }
```

And finally the deck-view adapter

```
    public class DeckAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Card> {

public DeckAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Card> currentDeck)
{
    super(context, 0, currentDeck); //call parent as constructor
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    //get data from card
    Card card = getItem(position);

    //check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(deck_layout, parent, false);
    }
    //get imageView and link to grid display
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);

    //get imageview id
    int cardIconId = card.getCardImgID(); //get image assigned to card and store as local int
    iv.setImageResource(cardIconId); //set image to view
    return convertView;

}
```

}

In theory, I wish to make an

```
    addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addToDeckButton);
            addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v, int position) {

                    currentDeck.add(database.get(position));
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
```

and put it into the database adapter's getView() method, but I couldn't get it to work no matter what I tossed in there. Any suggestions?

Comment: Couldn't get it to work how?  What did you try?  What did you want to happen?  What actually happened?

Comment: I tried to get the view position of the item and by passing both arraylists to the button, perform one operation to add the selected item of "database" to "current Deck". I've been searching for examples and every answer points to using the onClickListener but how can I make an onClickListener for a button that gets the arraylists? Do I have to create a custom onClickListener?

Comment: Is it possible to pass the ListView view as a parameter to the button or should i create an entirely onClickListener specifically for the button similar to my getView method?

Comment: Instead of describing what you did in a comment, edit your question to show what you did (i.e. the code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. By placing an onClick method inside the on-item click method, I produced the result I wanted. I'm actually upset it was that simple. I lost four days trying to figure this out.

```
     //set up click event for database
    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mMessageClickedHandler = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(final AdapterView parent, View v, final int position, long id) {
            //link image view
            ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cardDisplay);
            //link scrollable textview
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cardDataDisplay);
            // Do something in response to the click
            //set image id
            int imageId = database.get(position).getCardImgID();
            //display image to imageview
            iv.setImageResource(imageId);

            //Configure button click event
            addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //add card from database to current deck
                    currentDeck.add(database.get(position));
                    adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
```